# Выгрузка API данных из OZON в Google Sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Все доброго времени суток.

Пытаюсь получать сток на OZON по апи, выгружая через Google Scripts. Достиг определенных успехов по получению ответа на запрос, а вот в таблицу это распределить никак не получается.

Я не спец, больше интересуюсь такими вещами, посмотрел на гитхабе код, здесь в паре вопросов кое-что подсмотрел, слепил воедино, но сейчас не догоняю как разнести ответ JSON по ячейкам.

По ощущениям уже очень близко к финишу задача. Но хожу вокруг да около из-за отсутствия компетенции

Документация API Ozon https://docs.ozon.ru/api/seller/#operation/ProductAPI_GetProductInfoStocksV3
Вот код:

```
function GetStock() {
  const API_URL = "api-seller.ozon.ru";
  const endpoint = "/v3/product/info/stocks";
var data1 = {
  "filter": {
             "visibility": "ALL"
    },
    "limit": 100
};
var options = {
  method: "POST",
      headers:  {
        'Client-Id': 'Тут клиент айди',
        'Api-Key': 'Тут ключ',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data1)
};
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var APIPullSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Остатки (Озон)");
APIPullSheet.getRange('A:P').clearContent();

var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(API_URL + endpoint, options); //получаем ответ
var parcedData = JSON.parse(responseAPI.getContentText());
Logger.log(parcedData); // делаем лог, чтобы увидеть ответ до вывода в таблице

var results = new Array ();
  for(var i in parcedData.result)
    {
      var temp = [];
      for(var j in parcedData.result[i])
      {
        temp.push(parcedData.result[i][j]);
      }
      results.push(temp);
    }
resultRange = APIPullSheet.getRange(1, 1, results.length, 16);
resultRange.setValues(results);
 
}
```

Итог:
В логе вижу ответ озона, все хорошо

```
{result={total=16.0, items=[{offer_id=SK-000-001, product_id=1.78670937E8, stocks=[{reserved=0.0, present=0.0, type=fbs}, {type=fbo, reserved=0.0, present=17.0}]}, {stocks=[{type=fbs, present=0.0, reserved=0.0}, {type=fbo, reserved=0.0, present=0.0}], offer_id=SK-000-002, product_id=1.78725079E8}, {product_id=1.78733542E8, stocks=[{reserved=1.0, present=23.0, type=fbo}, {present=0.0, reserved=0.0, type=fbs}], offer_id=SK-000-003}, {stocks=[{reserved=0.0, type=fbs, present=0.0}, {present=0.0, type=fbo, reserved=0.0}], product_id=1.78740872E8, offer_id=SK-000-004}, {offer_id=SK-000-006, product_id=2.1758728E8, stocks=[{type=fbo, reserved=0.0, present=2.0}, {reserved=0.0, type=fbs, present=0.0}]}, {stocks=[{type=fbs, present=0.0, reserved=0.0}, {reserved=0.0, present=35.0, type=fbo}], product_id=2.18032455E8, offer_id=SK-000-007}, {offer_id=SK-000-009-Путешествия-doc1, product_id=2.45435953E8, stocks=[{type=fbo, reserved=0.0, present=24.0}, {reserved=0.0, present=0.0, type=fbs}]}, {stocks=[{reserved=0.0, present=0.0, type=fbs}, {type=fbo, present=30.0, reserved=0.0}], product_id=2.45435954E8, offer_id=SK-000-008-Море-doc1}, {stocks=[{present=0.0, type=fbs, reserved=0.0}, {reserved=0.0, present=28.0, type=fbo}], offer_id=SK-000-012-Книги-doc2, product_id=2.45435955E8}, {offer_id=SK-000-011-Волшебство-doc3, product_id=2.45435956E8, stocks=[{present=42.0, type=fbo, reserved=0.0}, {present=0.0, type=fbs, reserved=0.0}]}, {product_id=2.80105873E8, stocks=[{type=fbs, present=0.0, reserved=0.0}, {present=32.0, reserved=1.0, type=fbo}], offer_id=SK-000-013-Космос-doc3}, {stocks=[{present=0.0, type=fbs, reserved=0.0}, {reserved=1.0, present=22.0, type=fbo}], product_id=2.80105874E8, offer_id=SK-000-015-Котики-doc4}, {stocks=[{present=32.0, type=fbo, reserved=0.0}, {reserved=0.0, type=fbs, present=0.0}], offer_id=SK-000-006-Уют-doc4, product_id=2.80105875E8}, {stocks=[{type=fbs, reserved=0.0, present=0.0}, {type=fbo, present=34.0, reserved=0.0}], product_id=2.80105876E8, offer_id=SK-000-006-Уют-doc3}, {product_id=2.80105877E8, offer_id=SK-000-014-Лес-doc3, stocks=[{present=0.0, type=fbs, reserved=0.0}, {reserved=0.0, present=27.0, type=fbo}]}, {stocks=[{reserved=0.0, present=33.0, type=fbo}, {reserved=0.0, present=0.0, type=fbs}], offer_id=SK-000-010-Весна-doc2, product_id=2.80105878E8}], last_id=WzI4MDEwNTg3OCwyODAxMDU4Nzhd}}
```

Но выходит ошибка:

Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 0 but the range has 16.

А в таблице появляются заполненные ячейке с ответами, разбитыми по колонкам:
[image: То что появляется в таблице]

Плюс еще из-за того что параметре Stock есть подмассив с данными вида [{type=fbs, present=0.0, reserved=0.0}, {type=fbo, reserved=0.0, present=0.0}], данные стока выводятся с ошибками такого типа stocks=[Ljava.lang.Object;@269103f

Понимаю, что проблема в массиве в массиве

В общем, прошу направить или дать ответ как правильно сделать так, чтобы данные ответа API разносились по ячейкам и сток тоже разносился по ячейкам.

Итоговый вывод данных вижу примерно так:

[image: вид таблицы]

Спасибо большое всем за ответ!

Comment: какой язык? C#?

Comment: Google Script внутренний. Насколько я понимаю он вариация java script

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetStock() {
   const API_URL = "api-seller.ozon.ru";
   const endpoint = "/v3/product/info/stocks";
   var data1 = {
    "filter": {
             "visibility": "ALL"
    },
    "limit": 100
};
var options = {
  method: "POST",
      headers:  {
        'Client-Id': 'Тут клиент айди',
        'Api-Key': 'Тут ключ',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data1)
};
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var APIPullSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Остатки (Озон)");
APIPullSheet.getRange('A:P').clearContent();

var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(API_URL + endpoint, options); //получаем ответ
var parcedData = JSON.parse(responseAPI.getContentText());
Logger.log(parcedData); // делаем лог, чтобы увидеть ответ до вывода в таблице

///----------------------------------------------
var wh = parcedData.wh_items // присваиваем переменной результат json

for (i =0; i < wh.length;i++){
  for (j = 0 ; j < wh[0].items.length;  j++   ){
      var items = [
      wh[i].id,
      wh[i].name,
      wh[i].items[j].offer_id
      ]
  nwh.push(items)
  }
} 
sheet.getRange(3,1, nwh.length, nwh[0].length).setValues(nwh);

}
```

//-------------
Попробуйте доступ к массиву через объект
parcedData.wh_items (Это ключ к массиву данных, который будет в логе Logger.log(parcedData) ).
ниже будут items и т.д.

в зависимости от того, что выходит в массиве нужен for по каждому элементу, т.к. они разного уровня вложенности. Ну и зависит конечно же от того, в каком виде вы хотите их разместить на листе.
Например

//перебираем массив, чтобы все строчки были с данными, в моем случае так нужно было. id, name мне нужны были в одной строчке.
потом записываем это на лист.
Надеюсь ответ чем-то кому-то поможет :)